# What does [...] mean in Python code?

Tags: python, caffe

sample:

```
net.params['bbox_pred'][0].data[...] = orig_0
net.params['bbox_pred'][1].data[...] = orig_1
```

This code always appears in caffe predict code. But I don't know what the `[...]` means.